# How to test for argv count and value of argv[1] in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I am trying to test for the length of `$argv` or the value of the first `$argv[1]` element in a function like follows:

```
function do-something
  if test (count $argv) -lt 2 -o $argv[1] = "--help"
    echo Usage ...
  end
end
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
⟩ do-something 
test: Missing argument at index 6
```

The issue is with the string comparison, but I am not sure how to get this working. I have also tried `-o [ $argv[1] = "--help" ]`, but this fails with another error.

Note also that this works if I include an argument, so it seems `fish` is evaluating the second condition even if the first fails. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `(count $argv)` and `$argv[1]` both get expanded at the same time, as they are both arguments to the same command, and `$argv[1]` is empty if unset. So if there were no arguments, `test` sees:

`if test (count) -lt 2 -o = "--help"`

Resulting in an error.

The simplest way to fix this is by quoting `$argv[1]`:

```
if test (count $argv) -lt 2 -o "$argv[1]" = "--help"
```

The quotes ensure that `"$argv[1]"` expands to one argument (an empty string) instead of no arguments.

An alternative is to use two separate commands:

```
function do-something
  if test (count $argv) -lt 2; or test $argv[1] = "--help"
    echo Usage
  end
end
```

The second `test` will only execute if the first one succeeds.

Comment: Yes, I figured I could do it with the second way given what I discovered but thought it a bit odd coming from other programming languages. Thanks for the answer! (Prefer the first way.)